# Implementing BeginInvoke() in Office AddIn C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dispatcher, begininvoke

I have a method in my class code that I want to run asynchronously by  invoking it using **BeginInvoke()** . I had earlier attempted to use  a **Dispatcher** but it turns out it is not available for WinForms applications and Office addins,hence the use of BeginInvoke().

The code is below:

```
private delegate void InvokeMacroDelegate();

private void Process()
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeMacroDelegate(OnlineStream));
    }

private void OnlineStream()
    {
        //some process here
    }
```

I get the error below

> 'ThisAddIn' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke' and the
>   best extension method overload
>   'DispatcherExtensions.BeginInvoke(Dispatcher, Action)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'Dispatcher'

What's the problem here and what's the fix?
Thanks.

Comment: In `WinForms` available `Control.BeginInvoke`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, thanks,I've added using **using System.Windows.Forms;** but the error still persists.

Comment: @ch_av Did you resolve your issue? I have a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61052122/1232087).