# How can we call Invoke(Delegate) method from a Microsoft Office Add-in?

Tags: c#, delegates, vsto, office-interop, invoke

**Question**: How can we use [Invoke(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) method in a [Microsoft Office 2010-2016 VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) project. Or, are there any work around, alternatives etc for a `VSTO` project?

**Background**: I am trying to implement a source code of a third party [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/) application into my [Microsoft Office VSTO add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) project. The third party vendor has provided its users a sample/example as a Windows Form project with source code and has asked its users to mimic that code to their other projects (WPF, Office Solutions etc.).

I have been able to implement all parts of their Windows Forms sample app except the following line of code that is not recognized by the `VS2019` in my `VSTO` project:

```
    Invoke(new IsActivatedDelegate(CheckIfActivated));
```

**Remark**: `delegate void IsActivatedDelegate();` is a delegate declared in their sample's `Form1.cs` file and CheckIfActivated() is a method declared in the same `Form1.cs` file.

Now, we know that the [Invoke(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) method is from the `Control` class of System.Windows.Forms namespace. And, hence, cannot be used in a `VSTO` project. But there may be an alternative for a VSTO project.

**UPDATE**:

Following is an excerpt from the `Form1.cs` file of the third party's sample code that is calling [Invoke(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
...........
...........
void mnuActDeact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isGenuine)
    {
        // deactivate product without deleting the product key allows the user to easily reactivate
        try
        {
            ta.Deactivate(false);
        }
        catch (ThirdPartyObjectException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to deactivate: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        isGenuine = false;
        ShowTrial(true);
    }
    else
    {
        // Note: you can launch the ThirdPartyObject wizard or you can create you own interface

        // launch ThirdPartyObject.exe to get the product key from the user, and activate.
        Process TAProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),"ThirdPartyObject.exe")
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        TAProcess.Exited += p_Exited;
        TAProcess.Start();
    }
}

void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove the event
    ((Process) sender).Exited -= p_Exited;

    // the UI thread is running asynchronous to ThirdPartyObject closing that's why we can't call CheckIfActivated(); directly
    Invoke(new IsActivatedDelegate(CheckIfActivated));
}

delegate void IsActivatedDelegate();

void CheckIfActivated()
{
    bool isNowActivated = false;

    try
    {
        isNowActivated = ta.IsActivated();
    }
    catch (ThirdPartyObjectException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to check if activated: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    // recheck if activated
    if (isNowActivated)
    {
        isGenuine = true;
        ReEnableAppFeatures();
        ShowTrial(false);
    }
}
............
........
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

I wish you showed code for context sake... at least a few of the lines...buh I know this. if you have say

```
YourDelegate yd = new YourDelegate(YourMethod);
```

you can substitute:

```
yd.Invoke(new IsActivatedDelegate(CheckIfActivated));
```

with

```
yd(new IsActivatedDelegate(CheckIfActivated));
```